# Sending assembly code to OpenAI API result in to much token send. How can I manage to send big assembly code to ChatGPT API?

Tags: python, openai-api

I'm developping a Ghidra plugin in Python and try to send the assembly code of a malware to CHATGPT so it can provide very useful information about it.
The problem is I'm not allowed to send all my assembly code because of the token limitation.
Would someone have any idea how I could do so ChatGPT is able to receive it by chunk and understand all links between this assembly code?

I tried LongChain with Deeplake, but it doesn't work:

```
import os
from getpass import getpass
from langchain.embeddings.openai import OpenAIEmbeddings
from langchain.vectorstores import DeepLake
from langchain.text_splitter import CharacterTextSplitter
from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
from langchain.chains import ConversationalRetrievalChain
from langchain.document_loaders import TextLoader



os.environ['OPENAI_API_KEY'] = "MYKEY"
# Please manually enter OpenAI Key
os.environ['ACTIVELOOP_TOKEN'] = "MYKEY"
embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings()


root_dir = 'functions'
docs = []
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(root_dir):
    for file in filenames:
        try: 
            loader = TextLoader(os.path.join(dirpath, file), encoding='utf-8')
            docs.extend(loader.load_and_split())
        except Exception as e: 
            pass

print(f'{len(docs)}')

text_splitter = CharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=1000, chunk_overlap=0)
texts = text_splitter.split_documents(docs)
print(f'{len(texts)}')
username = "mathiashanquiniaux" # replace with your username from app.activeloop.ai
db = DeepLake(dataset_path=f"hub://{username}/Thesis3", embedding_function=embeddings) #dataset would be publicly available
db.add_documents(texts)

db = DeepLake(dataset_path=f"hub://{username}/Thesis3", read_only=True, embedding_function=embeddings)
retriever = db.as_retriever()
retriever.search_kwargs['distance_metric'] = 'cos'
retriever.search_kwargs['fetch_k'] = 100
retriever.search_kwargs['maximal_marginal_relevance'] = True
retriever.search_kwargs['k'] = 10

model = ChatOpenAI(model='gpt-3.5-turbo') # switch to 'gpt-4'
qa = ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm(model,retriever=retriever)

questions = [
    "I want you to act as a reverse engineering expert and help me to do some reverse engineering on a malware. I want you to explain this code with as much details as you can. Explaining what it does and how it works.",
    "What can you say about these functions?",
] 
chat_history = []

for question in questions:  
    result = qa({"question": question, "chat_history": chat_history})
    chat_history.append((question, result['answer']))
    print(f"-> **Question**: {question} \n")
    print(f"**Answer**: {result['answer']} \n")
```